# GeoSpark Zeppelin helium plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to enable geospark-zeppelin helium plugin but am unable to see the geospark-zeppelin button as described in this [link](http://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/download/zeppelin/).

I use the Zeppelin (0.8.0) available in AWS EMR cluster.

Here is the geospark-zeppelin.json that i placed under /usr/lib/zeppelin/helium/ folder

```
{
  "type": "VISUALIZATION",
  "name": "geospark-zeppelin",
  "description": "Zeppelin visualization support for GeoSpark",
  "artifact": "/home/heliumZep/GeoSpark/geospark-zeppelin",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "icon": "<i class='fa fa-globe'></i>"
}
```

After this, I could see the geospark-zeppelin package under the helium plugin. I enabled the same as well.

Now the problem is that i am not able to see the geospark-zeppelin button in the notebook. Am i missing something? The artifact path in the above json points to some local folder where zeppelin is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download all the files from [this github page](https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/tree/master/zeppelin) and put them in the directory you set here "artifact": "/home/heliumZep/GeoSpark/geospark-zeppelin".